# Adding delay to DPDT switch

Tags: dc, delay, dpdt

[image]

I have a simple circuit with a DPDT switch like this that I'm using to switch polarity on a linear actuator. The issue is that I'm using the actuator to toggle the switch, and there is a dead zone between the two switch positions that the linear actuator doesn't move past. (The switch only has two positions).

How can I add a little delay or otherwise modify the circuit so that the linear actuator can toggle the switch and reverse the polarity (so that it can automatically come backwards once it has gone far enough)?

Comment: @glen_geek That would make the problem worse. The motor powers a linear actuator, it moves in one direction and when it reaches a certain point the actuator flips the switch and reverses the direction. Except that when the switch gets halfway the power to the motor is lost and the motor stops. They want to keep the motor going enough to fully flip the switch.

Comment: You may want a switch that is "make before break", whereas you likely have "break before make".   What that means is, in your circuit, the current flow stops because the switch is "open".   If you use make-before-break, then there is no point where it's a totally open circuit, BOTH poles of the switch (briefly) are connected.    Unfortunately it also means the battery will be (briefly) short-circuited.  That may or may not be OK in your application.  If this simple fix doesn't cut it, you'll have to get a more elaborate circuit in place, i.e. relays or transistors...

Comment: That may make things worse still as it'll short the battery and the motor, causing it to stop quicker and leave the switch stuck in its shorted state.

Comment: I think the most economical solution is to use a switch with a center off. Many will not let you go from one on to the other on, you have to pause in the center off spot.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you should replace the switch.

A snap-action switch such as a microswitch should not have a dead zone between positions no matter how slowly you move the actuator.

Answer (score 2):

Use a DPDT relay to swap power polarity to the actuator instead of the switch.

The switch can then be used to feed power to the relay coil when the actuator reaches it. This won't happen until the switch is fully moved to the on position and will then reverse the power and start moving the actuator back again.

Comment: this setup does not guarantee that the switch switches all the way. the actuator may hang at one end switching the relay back and forth really fast,

Comment: but if you made the relay drive itself and used two limit switches that could work

Comment: @Jasen As long as the switch doesn't activate the relay until fully closed it will work fine. OP doesn't appear to have any requirement for continuous back and forth operation, which would need bistable control and limit switches.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean, so long as the switch is well behaved in one direction that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Of course another switch or two limit switches combined with a bistable latching relay could solve this.
This is a very simple approach using only a few electronic components.

There is no motor voltage or current specified. The needed additional time is also unknown. So I just assumed a small 12V motor with 100 mA current consumption.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYi3FD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The energy needed for a fraction of a second can be stored in an electrolytic capacitor.
- The polar nature of these capacitors requires either a complex circuit or just one for each polarity.
- The diodes bypass the current across the capacitor with wrong polarity for the given input voltage.
- The resistors limit the inrush current after polarity change.
- When the supply is off, a transfer current from the charged capacitor to the discharged one flows through the motor until the are equally charged.

Answer (score 1):

Put a spring on the switch actuator so that the switch gives a reliable snap-action, if necessary find a switch with stronger detents.

Else use a latching relay to control the motor direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how, using two standard electromagnetic relays.

[image]

Time delay is not required.